# Jumbotron overlapping previous elements in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I was trying to experiment with container, container-fluid, jumbotron classes of bootstrap 4. The HTML code i used is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="container">contaigjnohjbofitujkiner</h1>
<h1 class="container-fluid">containfhonjoiyjboifgber</h1>
<span class="jumbotron">jumbotofgbnoitrjbogiftjron</span>
</body>
</html>
```

In the output of this file I noticed that span element with jumbotron class was slightly overlapping h1 element with container-fluid class. I want to understand why this happened is this a bug in firefox quantum? or is it because any property of jumbotron or container-fluid in bootstrap 4?

Comment: because a `span` is `display: inline;` by default, so it is rendering inline. Change it to a `div` and it will be `display:block;` and not overlap. this is not related to Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zgood said in his comment, the `span` is a `display: inline` element by default.

Here are some characteristics of it:

- The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
- The `<span>` tag provides no visual change by itself.
- The `<span>` tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or
  a    part of a document.

Your question aked why `span` was overlapping `h1` element with `container-fluid` class. And, how I said before, because of the inline propriety.

Check out this example, using a `<div>` and see how it is no more overlapping.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="container">Lorem ipsum - Container</h1>
  <h1 class="container-fluid">Lorem ipsum - Container Fluid</h1>
  <div class="jumbotron">Lorem ipsum - Jumbotron</div>
</body>
</html>
```